# Work with DatagridView cells type

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**Context:**

I'm working on C#, WinForm, and my question is about DataGridView, and precisely, cells type.

I need to get datas from an API, and after some filters, show them in a DataGridView.
Based on winform, and not beeing responsable of the GUI, I need to work with what I got.

So actually, datas and cells type are already defined, as following:
[Text] - [Text] - [Checkbox] - [HyperLink] - [Button]

Text and Checkbox are easily done, but my problems come from Link and Button

**Needs:**

Link and Button need to have a text and a value.
Text will always be the same ("View on website " and "Download"), but need to be localized.
Value will change depending on API for each entity.
On Link click, it will open the browser to the url (link value), and on Button Click, it will download a file.

**Problems:**

All my search went to a final point.
Tuto and questions are answered by: Define a DataGridView in code, and then, contruct columns type, etc.
On my side, this isn't possible, since columns type already are defined by developper in charge of GUI side.

Actually, I tryed this.
(not working for both Link and Button)

```
private void BindGrid(List<ProductModel> listProducts)
{
    foreach(var product in listProducts)
    {

        var websiteLink = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
        websiteLink.Value = product.WebsiteDetailsUrl;

        var buttonDownload = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
        buttonDownload.Value = product.UpdateUrl;
        buttonDownload.ToolTipText = "Download";

        //                    [Text]          [Text]          [Checkbox]    [HyperLink]     [Button]
        grid_Products.Rows.Add(product.Title, product.Type, product.IsPaid, websiteLink, buttonDownload);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lots for any tips or advice.

Comment: `grid_Products.DataSource = listProducts;` in `BindGrid` method should be enough if `developper in charge of GUI side` did his work properly

Comment: It isn't working, because some field aren't set to Column. Also, how events are supposed to be bind on my side? Generic button click with event button value as parameter?